# Does the locale Have a Facet That Defines the Negative Symbol?

Tags: c++, localization, locale, number-formatting, negative-number

I would have expected the [`numpunct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct) facet to have contained information about the character to use for the negative symbol.

Can I find this information somewhere else in the locale, or do I just have to assume that it's always `'-'`?

Comment: If you look [`num_put::put`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put/put) at it states *For both integer and floating-point types, if showpos is set, the modifier + is prepended* so it looks like + and - might be universal.

Comment: @NathanOliver I didn't expect that but other than the parenthesis (which I think are already denoted in `moneypunct`) I've never seen it any other way. Perhaps you could write an answer using that as a supporting argument. Seems as strong as any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at [`num_put::put`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put/put) for `showpos` it states

> For both integer and floating-point types, if `showpos` is set, the modifier `+` is prepended

So that leads me to believe that `+` will always be used for representing a positive number

Additionally [[locale.numpunct]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/locale.numpunct#2) has

> ```
> integer   ::= [sign] units
> sign      ::= plusminus
> plusminus ::= '+' | '-'
> ```

Which I interpret as meaning it will always use `-` for a negative number and `+` if it is positive and `showpos` is `true`.  If that wasn't the case I would expect it to be like

> ```
> integer   ::= [sign] units
> sign      ::= plusminus
> plusminus ::= plus | minus
> ```